# MPI-IO write to file in non contiguous pattern

Tags: mpi, mpi-io

I am having trouble in writing a parallel MPI I/O program that will write in a particular pattern.
I was able to have process 0 write integers 0-9, process 1 write integers 10-19, process 2 write integers 20-29, etc.

```
proc 0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
proc 1: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
proc 2: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
proc 3: [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
result: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20
```

Here is the code that accomplishes that:

```c
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // MPI_Finalize();

    int i, rank, size, offset;
    MPI_File fhw;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    int N = size * 10;
    int buf[N];
    for ( i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
        buf[i] = rank * 10 + i;
    }

    offset = rank * (N/size) * sizeof(int);
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "datafile", MPI_MODE_CREATE|MPI_MODE_WRONLY,
                MPI_INFO_NULL, &fhw);
    printf("(%d) Writing to file...\n", rank);
    printf("\nRank: (%d), Offset: %d\n", rank, offset);
    MPI_File_write_at(fhw, offset, buf, (N/size), MPI_INT, &status);
    MPI_File_close(&fhw);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

However, I am confused about how I should produce the following result:

```
// starting out:
proc 0: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
proc 1: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
proc 2: [20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
proc 3: [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39]
// proc 0 writes first 2 slots, then proc 1 writes next 2, etc.
result: [0, 1, 10, 11, 20, 21, 30, 31, 2, 3, 12, 13, 22, 23, ..., 8, 9, 18, 19, 28, 29, 38, 29]
```

I have tried using `MPI_File_set_view` while looking up examples and documentation online for the past few hours but cannot get it to work.  Can someone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: Note on efficiency: Using strides is always a killer! It really depend the number of processes you use, the size of continuous blocks, the size of the file and the number of disks... If your file is a few Gb and you got 200 stripes on your cluster, then it is fine... But having a file of a few Tb, using order >10k processes, the best but really the best is always writing your file with each processes writing continuously in your file. By experience you might gain a factor 10 in I/O bandwidth...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you had understood you need to setup a view...

Then some small mistake in your code:
1) Do you really need a buf of more that 10 number for each processes?
2) The offset in MPI_File_wite_at is note in byte, but in number of element (in respect of the element size of your view)

So to set up the view you only need 1 line:

```c
#include "mpi.h"
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // MPI_Finalize();                                                                                                      

    int i, rank, size, offset;
    MPI_File fhw;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    int N = 10; 
    int buf[N];
    for ( i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
        buf[i] = rank * 10 + i;
    }

    offset = 10*rank;
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD,"datafile",MPI_MODE_CREATE|MPI_MODE_WRONLY,
                MPI_INFO_NULL, &fhw);
    printf("(%d) Writing to file...\n", rank);
    printf("\nRank: (%d), Offset: %d\n", rank, offset);
    MPI_File_set_view( fhw,0,MPI_INT, MPI_INT, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL ) ;
    MPI_File_write_at(fhw, offset, buf, N, MPI_INT, &status);
    MPI_File_close(&fhw);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Then you can do exactly the same using MPI_File_write :-), and setting the view differently for each processes, just replace the view and write:

```c
MPI_File_set_view(fhw,offset*sizeof(int),MPI_INT,MPI_INT,
                        "native",MPI_INFO_NULL ) ;
MPI_File_write_at(fhw, 0, buf, N, MPI_INT, &status);
```

or simply:

```c
MPI_File_set_view(fhw,offset*sizeof(int),MPI_INT,MPI_INT,
                        "native",MPI_INFO_NULL ) ;
MPI_File_write(fhw, buf, N, MPI_INT, &status);
```

NOTE: in view the offset is in byte, while in write it is in size of elements of the view.... Might be a bit confusing :-)

Then the magics:

You need to write blocks of 2 ints with a stride of 2*size, and you have N/2 of those blocks, so you create a type:

```c
MPI_Type_vector(N/2, 2 , size*2,  MPI_INT, &ftype);
MPI_Type_commit(&ftype);
```

and set the view:

```c
MPI_File_set_view( fhw, rank*2*sizeof(int), MPI_INT, ftype, "native", MPI_INFO_NULL ) ;
```

then you have to think that in memory you have a continuous storage of your data, to fit your view, it has to be something as N/2 blocks, so you create a datatype:

```c
MPI_Type_contiguous(2,   MPI_INT, &mtype);
MPI_Type_commit(&mtype);
```

Then you are ready for the write:

```c
MPI_File_write(fhw, buf, N/2, mtype, &status);
MPI_File_close(&fhw);
```

And so the entire code will become:

```c
#include "mpi.h"
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int i, rank, size, offset;
    MPI_File fhw;
    MPI_Status status;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    int N = 10; //need to be even!!!
    int buf[N];
    for ( i = 0; i < N; ++i ) {
        buf[i] = rank * N + i;
    }

    offset = 10*rank;
    MPI_File_open(MPI_COMM_WORLD, "datafile", MPI_MODE_CREATE|MPI_MODE_WRONLY,
                    MPI_INFO_NULL, &fhw);
    printf("(%d) Writing to file...\n", rank);
    printf("\nRank: (%d), Offset: %d\n", rank, offset);

    MPI_Datatype ftype,mtype;
    MPI_Type_vector(N/2, 2 , size*2,  MPI_INT, &ftype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&ftype);

    MPI_File_set_view( fhw, rank*2*sizeof(int), MPI_INT, ftype,
                         "native",MPI_INFO_NULL ) ;

    MPI_Type_contiguous(2,   MPI_INT, &mtype);
    MPI_Type_commit(&mtype);

    MPI_File_write(fhw, buf, N/2, mtype, &status);
    MPI_File_close(&fhw);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oups I submit it before finishing to write it... so now its complete :-)

Comment: if performance matters, you should really use collective I/O. `mtype` is not needed here, so the write command could be `MPI_File_write_all(fhw, buf, N, MPI_INT, &status);`

Comment: I am not sure, if you have 2 object yes, but if it become a big number is it not better to have the block grouped? Then indeed write_all would be better

Comment: I would expect the MPI implementation handles this pretty well, so I'd rather keep the user code as simple as possible.

Answer (score 1):

MPI File views are a little complicated, sure.  Break it down process by process:

```
rank 0:  0 1 - - - - - - 2 3 - - - - - - 4 5
rank 1:  - - 10 11 - - - - - - 12 13 - - - - - -
rank 2:  - - - - 20 21 - - - - - -
rank 3:  - - - - - - 30 31 - - - - - -
```

You have a lot of MPI datatypes to chose from.  Which one is appropriate?

- With enough work, the most general STRUCT type can express anything, but you are working entirely with MPI_INT, so STRUCT is overkill
- You could enumerate the offsets and blocklens with an INDEXED type, but your pattern is regular: each block is two integers
- You could therefore use BLOCKINDEXED.  However, the spacing between blocks is regular, too, making BLOCKINDEXED more than we need
- VECTOR.. now we are getting somewhere.

In C, VECTOR's prototype is this:

```
int MPI_Type_vector(int count, int blocklength, int stride,
                    MPI_Datatype oldtype, MPI_Datatype *newtype)
```

In this example, you want each process to write a vector with 5 blocks.  Each block has two elements.  The stride between the start of each block is 2*nprocs or 8.   The 'oldtype' is MPI_INT.

You are using MPI_FILE_WRITE_AT already.  Maybe consider MPI_FILE_WRITE_AT_ALL to take advantage of any collective i/o optimizations the library might provide.

Comment: Nice answer, but I think it helpfull only if you know how to do it :-)